# I want to filter a particular record from table to my excel using vba macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table like -
[my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1TpI.png)

I want to fetch a particular record based on any of the columns of the table.

Like if, I take (var MyFamily)family name as Mozart then it has to return all the data of the particular record. Like-

MyFamily.Department should return Marketing and MyFamily.Given_Name should return Wolfgang

Comment: `MyFamily` would be a new object that you create using a class module. But what is the question?

Comment: Please include the table in your question or attach the image as an inline image, see [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). And try to include some code, showing what you have already tried so far.